# Would like to start my Blog on SharePoint Platform, need directions

Tags: blog, hosting

I would like to start my own blog, as I have been working on SharePoint for couple years now; I want my site to hosted as a SharePoint 2010 Application.

So, I need help interms of

-> Good Hosting provider to offer me a Sharepoint webapplication 
-> would like to know the cost model (WebApplication , sitecollection)

Any other experiences worth sharing?

Comment: Why would you do this - SP doesn't really make a great public facing blog, its not its focus. Do you want a blog or a SharePoint project?

Comment: I was looking for a sharepoint playground, where I own a webapplication to demo all my POCs I do and also blog about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two companies popular with Sharepointers are fpweb.net and rackspace.com.

Comment: I've used SharePoint sites with both companies and have been more happy with them than others.